# how to solve this ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found?

Tags: mysql

I want to install Mysql on my MAC machine. When I do

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

It is showing error some thing like

> "ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/Concurs-MacBook-Pro-8.local.pid)".

I tried all the methods which people posted in other posts but I did not get any thing out of it. Could any one please help me with steps to install new mysql and to remove old one?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about MAC, but the pid file stores the process id and is used as a lock so that you don't end up with loads of MySql's running.

I'd have to guess that the user id or group under which MySql runs can't write the pid into the data folder. If it were Linux, I'd be making sure that the data folder and data files had group ownership changed to MYSQL (or whatever it's supposed to be on the MAC).